# How to search many values with Postgres trigram?

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

If I have a table with the values name and surname, how do I search for those two values?

## Example

I set a threshold to filter out unwanted values, and then I can find similarity with table name and searched text; however, if there is only name or surname, it's OK; but if both are combined, the similarity is different.

But in function `similarity` I am able to put only one value `name` or `surname`

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.8;

SELECT name, surname, similarity(name, 'seaching text') AS sml
  FROM goods_goods
  WHERE name %  'seaching text'
  ORDER BY sml DESC, name
```

How can I put more values in a similar function? Like this `similarity((name,surname and so on if necessary), 'seaching text')`

---

## EDITED

#### One More Example To Clarify

- Table name is `table`
- There is three columns `sentence1`, `sentence2`, `sentence3`

I want to find the most similar row in which the searching string is most similar to `sentence1`, `sentence2`, `sentence3` All in one, not separated sentences.

#### Here an example with some

table

```
|      sentence1    |   sentence2   |      sentence3     |
|-------------------|---------------|--------------------|
|  I have an apple  |  Samsung Tv   |  Dji mavic 2 Zoom  |
|-------------------|---------------|--------------------|
|  Tiger is red!!!  |  postgresql   |  Dji mavic 2 Zoom  |
|-------------------|---------------|--------------------|
|  Basketball ABCD  |  battery AC   |  Dji mavic 3 Zoom  |
|-------------------|---------------|--------------------|
|  Tiger is red!!!  |  postgresql   |  Dji mavic 3 Zoom  |
```

and now my seraching text is something like `Tiger postgres dji mavic 2`

As we can see most similar is row number `2` --> 61% but row `4` is 57% it's correct because there is `...mavic 3` but we want `...mavic 2`

```
select strict_word_similarity('I have an apple Samsung Tv Dji mavic 2 Zoom','Tiger postgres dji mavic 2' ) --> 0.27906978

select strict_word_similarity('Tiger is red!!! postgresql Dji mavic 2 Zoom','Tiger postgres dji mavic 2' ) --> 0.61904764

select strict_word_similarity('Basketball ABCD battery AC Dji mavic 3 Zoom','Tiger postgres dji mavic 2' ) --> 0.24390244

select strict_word_similarity('Tiger is red!!! postgresql Dji mavic 2 Zoom','Tiger postgres dji mavic 2' ) --> 0.5714286
```

But if we compare each column one by one, there are columns  which is similar, but all  sentences together is completely wrong.
Like row one and two in sentence3 have same text, but first row is not what I want.

So How can i do that with pg_trgm?

Comment: Your problem is not clearly defined, so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want this:

```
SELECT name, surname, greatest(similarity(name, 'seaching text'),similarity(surname, 'seaching text'))  AS sml
FROM goods_goods
WHERE name % 'seaching text' or surname % 'seaching text' 
ORDER BY sml DESC, name
```

Comment: In that moment I don't think this is what i want. I tried to add one more example(edited question). Maybe now it would be more clear

Comment: @Dmiich I don't see how that is different. Or are you really just looking for `similarity(name || ' ' || surname, 'seaching text')`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes!!! This is what i want. Where can i find more information about this double line `||`? Or how it is called?

Comment: @Dmiich It's the string concatenation operator, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html. Alternatively you might want to use `concat_ws(' ', sentence1, sentence2, sentence3)`, especially if some of them can be `NULL`